# Left Navigation Box pointing to old Project Server after Migration

Tags: sharepoint-2007, project-server

I have migrated the Project Server using the method shown [here](http://lkar.blogspot.com/2008/05/moving-moss-project-server-2007.html).

I am able to see all the data. However the Navigation box is pointing to the old Server. [Like the Server Settings, Personal Settings etc]

Is there a way to tell the new server to look into its own data and not to the old server.

Please help me.

Is there any tool which would make the link redirect to the server we want?

Comment: Is there any body who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the linking to the old server might be saved in settings somewhere as part of the data. When the data was migrated, this old linking was also included.

Is there a way to check your app's settings to see whether these URL's are hardcoded? If you have no luck navigating the GUI, an alternative suggestion might be do manually search the database for the links.

Comment: Yeah I too think the same, however we are not supposed to change the SQL database directly as per MS guidelines!

Comment: If you are at least able to find where it is in the database, based on the tables which it's in, you could determine where that piece gets managed in the GUI.